# Using CallbackQueue

Tags: ros, spinonce, callbackqueue

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a code where I have already subscribed to the following topics

```
pose_sub = n2.subscribe("RosAria/pose", 1, poseCallback);
scan_sub = n.subscribe("scan", 1, scanCallback);
```

I am using ros::spinOnce() to callback to these topics. However, for a part of my code,I want to just monitor the pose messages and enter into poseCallback from inside a particular loop. However during this execution, I do not want to enter into the scanCallback function. I know this is possible but I am not very sure about its implementation.
I came across this article [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning) which mentions about using CallbackQueue but I did not understand its implementation or rather its application completely. Could anyone suggest whether it is this feature that I should be using or is there any other way I could get hold of the pose messages during the execution of my inner loop
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187321/using-callbackqueue/) by [Ashesh Goswami](https://answers.ros.org/users/8051/ashesh-goswami/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2014-07-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I also had the same doubts. After you asked the question, I decided to find out.

Here is some working code that should make things very clear.

If someone can assist me in making this a tutorial, it will be great.

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <ros/callback_queue.h>
#include <ros/callback_queue_interface.h>

#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>

void callback_1(const std_msgs::EmptyConstPtr& _msg)
{
    ROS_INFO("Called callback_1\n");
}

void callback_2(const std_msgs::EmptyConstPtr& _msg)
{
    ROS_INFO("Called callback_2\n");
}

int main(int argn, char* args[])
{
    ros::init(argn, args, "callback_q_subscriber");
    ros::NodeHandle nh_1;
    ros::NodeHandle nh_2;
    
    ros::CallbackQueue queue_1, queue_2;

    nh_1.setCallbackQueue(&queue_1);
    nh_2.setCallbackQueue(&queue_2);
    
    ros::Subscriber s_1 = nh_1.subscribe("/topic_1", 1, callback_1);
    ros::Subscriber s_2 = nh_2.subscribe("/topic_2", 1, callback_2);
    
    pthread_t id_1, id_2;
    
    int i = 20;
    while(i--)
    {
        queue_1.callOne(ros::WallDuration(1.0)); // can also be callAvailable()
    }
    
    i = 20;
    while(i--)
    {
        queue_2.callOne(ros::WallDuration(1.0)); // can also be callAvailable()
    }
    
    ROS_INFO("Hurray!");
    
    return 0;   
}
```

STEP 1:

Create a catkin package called callback_queue_test or what have you.

```
catkin_create_pkg callback_queue_test roscpp std_msgs
```

STEP 2:

```
a. Open favorite editor and paste the code inside it. Save it as simple.cpp.
b. Edit CMakeLists.txt to add an executable called simple_node. Add the target_link_libraries() for it.
```

STEP 3:

Open 4 terminals. Run the following in each in the same order.

```
a. roscore
b. rostopic pub -r 10 /topic_1 std_msgs/Empty
c. rostopic pub -r 10 /topic_2 std_msgs/Empty
d. rosrun callback_queue_test simple_node
```

That's it.

Have a nice day!

---

Originally posted by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) with karma: 1247 on 2014-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ashesh Goswami](https://answers.ros.org/users/8051/ashesh-goswami/) on 2014-07-21**:
Hey, thanks a ton. I can get my code to perform the same function. I had almost implemented the same thing except I had not given ros::WallDuration(1.0) as a parameter while calling callOne(). But now my problem seems to be solved. Once again, thanks a lot.

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-07-22**:
The ros::WallDuration is a timeout. I also assumed that there ought to be a default value. But, I think it is very low. For me without the WallDuration, the callback never happened.

**Comment by [Ashesh Goswami](https://answers.ros.org/users/8051/ashesh-goswami/) on 2014-07-22**:
It might be the reason. Anyway, thanks a lot. In case if anyone finds out why the code doesnt work without mentioning WallDuration, please let me know.

**Comment by [ZiyangLI](https://answers.ros.org/users/3542/ziyangli/) on 2015-01-24**:
where is `pthread` used?

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-08-18**:
What's the use of the line "pthread_t id_1, id_2;" ?

**Comment by [ashwath1993](https://answers.ros.org/users/29093/ashwath1993/) on 2017-12-08**:
Where do I call the callAvailable() if I have the nodehandle in a class?

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2017-12-08**:
You should probably make a public member function to do that.

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2017-12-08**:
@ZiyangLI never used. Probably some old code leftover.